# Azure Mobile App - Multi-language SQL colum

Tags: c#, azure

I have looked around the internet but I think I am approaching this question incorrect therefore I was unable to get any direction.

I have azure Mobile App and I am using c# backend.

I have one table with two columns "Title" and "URL" so I store web page title and URL in this table, the issue is if a web page has some other language as a page title my table in azure cannot recognize this and replaces it with some strange characters.

For example the following
[image]

I came across this article and it looks pretty straight forward to add other languages with English if the SQL column is nvarchar for example and we use 'N' in our insert statement.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/25/sql-server-storing-data-in-hindi-chinese-gujarati-and-tamil-or-any-other-language-in-the-same-table/

But how do I do that in azure Mobile App with c# backend? 
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After individually check each of my functions I figured that it was my own API not getting correct encoding for TITLE field

Adding the following to in HTTP Client resolved the issue

```
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```